# Comparing odds ratios - conditional or unconditional MLE

Tags: r, ratio, odds

When comparing log(OR) from two contingency tables using Z-test should I use conditional maximum likelihood estimate of odds ratios (as given by fisher.test in R) or simple unconditional?